# Using \cellcolor in powerdot

Tags: tables, color, powerdot

I'm trying to highlight some cells in a table in powerdot and \cellcolor doesn't work. How can I color some cells or rows in powerdot.

This is the table I used in a report and I'm trying to add to my presentation.

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Atividades & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{Ano 2} \\
    \hline 
    {} & \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 1} & \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 2} &
     \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 3} & \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 4} &
     \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 5} & \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 6} &
     \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 7} & \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 8} & 
     \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 9} & \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 10} &
     \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 11} & \cellcolor{green}\parbox{0.6cm}{\centering Mês \\ 12} \\[0.2cm]
    \hline
    \parbox{3cm}{Desenvolvimento da \\modelagem sísmica} & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x &  &  \\[0.2cm]
    \hline
    \parbox{3cm}{Técnicas de otimização \\matemática} &  &  &  & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\[0.2cm]
    \hline
    \parbox{3cm}{Envio de artigo de \\revista comparando as \\técnicas de otimização} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & x \\[0.2cm]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very descriptive? do you get an error? Please always post a complete small document that shows the error, we only need one row of the table, but we need to see the surrounding document. Did you load `colortbl` for example which defines `\cellcolor`

Comment: why have you declared the first column to be p(arbox) of width 2cm  but put a 3cm wide parbox in each cell?

Comment: This comment answered my question! In my report, I used \usepackage[table]{xcolor}. This way doesn't work in powerdot. The package colortbl worked beautifully! Thanks

I changed the size of the parbox to fit the slide. I forgot to change the sizes for each line... The original was 3cm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\cellcolor` is defined in the `colortbl` package.